# svn: add all my new files and directories

Tags: shell, subversion

I'm using Solaris 10. I need to add to SVN everything I've placed in the sub directories of my SVN checkout. I have added files and directories and sub directories - is there a command to take care of everything at once?

If not, is there a command I can run to list all the items I have added that have not been added to SVN yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your file names don't contain whitespace or `\"'`:

```
svn status | sed -n 's/^? *//p' | xargs svn add
```

To cope with any file name that doesn't begin with a space or contain a newline:

```
(IFS='
' set -f; svn add $(svn status | sed -n 's/^? *//p') )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
svn status | awk '{$1=""; print $0}' | xargs -i svn add "{}"
```

This adds all files with spaces.